# IndexError : list index out of range while looping

Tags: python, json, python-requests, index-error

When running the function with the following segment of code, I'm getting

> IndexError: list index out of bounds error

```py
#header value
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Key '+ api_key,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

#payload value
payload = {
    "inputs":[
        {
            "data":{
                "image":{
                    "url": image_url
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

response = requests.post('https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/bd367be194cf45149e75f01d59f77ba7/outputs', headers=headers, json=payload)
tags=[]
#print(response.json())
for x in response.json()["outputs"][0]["data"]["concepts"]:
    tags.append(x['name'])
return tags
```

Why is the index going out of range and How do I solve this.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure response.json()["outputs"] is returning a non empty list ?

Comment: what is the output of `print(response.json())`

Comment: yes the response.json()["outputs"]... works

Comment: Whats is the output ?

Comment: print(response.json()) gives :: status : code :10000 description : OK and prints the whole output .

Comment: Can you provide `headers` and `payload` values?

Comment: Link to output for response.json() : https://ibb.co/16yHqYc
The last two lines are output when print(tags) is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x is a list. Modify it to x[0]["name"] and you should be good to go.